# Minimum distance between two nodes in tree

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a unweighted and undirected tree with N nodes and N-1 edges I need to find minimum distance between source S and destination D.

Code :

```
vector<vector<int> >G(110);

bool check(int node,vector<int>path)
{
    for(int i=0;i<path.size();++i)
    {
        if(path[i]==node)
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int findMinpath(int source,int target,int totalnode,int totaledge)
{
    vector<int>path;
    path.push_back(source);
    queue<vector<int> >q;
    q.push(path);
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        path=q.front();
        q.pop();
        int lastNode=path[path.size()-1];
        if(lastNode==target)
        {
            return path.size()-1;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<G[lastNode].size();++i){
            if(check(G[lastNode][i],path)){
                vector<int>new_path(path.begin(),path.end());
                new_path.push_back(G[lastNode][i]);
                q.push(new_path);
         }}}
    return 1;
}
```

And then in main :

```
int N,S,E;
cin>>N>>S>>E;
for(int i=1;i<=N-1;++i)
{
    int u,v;
    cin>>u>>v;
    G[u].push_back(v);
    G[v].push_back(u);
 }
 cout<<findpaths(S,E,N,N-1)<<"\n";
```

Can it be further optimised as I need just minimum distance between S and E

Comment: Push nodes to your queue, not vectors...

Comment: @IVlad What ? I didn/t get you

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be pushing vectors to your queue, each vector containing the actual path so far. But you can get away with only pushing nodes, since you only use the last node in those vectors anyway, and instead store the distance to each node from the source.

This will be much faster because you won't be copying vectors at each step.

Keep track of the distances in an array and also use them to make sure you don't visit a node multiple times.

Untested, but should get the point across:

```
int distance[110 + 1]; // d[i] = distance from source to i, initialize with a large number

int findMinpath(int source,int target,int totalnode,int totaledge)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= totalnode; ++i)
    {
        distance[i] = 2000000000;
    }

    queue<int> q;
    q.push(source);
    distance[source] = 0;
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        node=q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(node==target)
        {
            return distance[node];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<G[node].size();++i){
            if(distance[node] + 1 < distance[ G[node][i] ]){
                distance[ G[node][i] ] = distance[node] + 1
                q.push(G[node][i]);
         }}}
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @IVIad I think their is some implementation issues

Comment: @user3840069 - like what?

Comment: @IVIad I think we need to check if node is visited or not. Like their can be case when node=target and yet answer is not reached yet

Comment: @user3840069 - that is taken care of in the `if` condition inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @IVIad Also root of tree is always node 1.

Comment: No, if you remove the target node from the queue, that will definitely be the shortest path.

Comment: Not more efficiently, but if you want to force things then sure.

Comment: @IVIad Ohk But I am getting wrong results for this one now.May be some boundary cases we need to handle

Comment: @user3840069 - for what tree are you getting a wrong result and what's the correct result?